# $A$ = ($a_{ij}$) with $a_{12}$ = $1$; $a_{ij}$ = $0$ for all $(i,j)$ not eqal to $(1, 2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us consider an $n$x $n$ matrix $A$ = ($a_{ij}$) with $a_{12}$ = $1$; $a_{ij}$ = $0$ for all $(i,j)$ not eqal to $(1, 2)$.
How to prove that there is no invertible matrix $P$ such that PA$P^{-1}$ is a diagonal
matrix.

Comment: have you studied diagonalisable matrices?

Comment: yes.I know that if algebraic multiplicity and geometric multiplicity are equal then the matrix is diagonalisable.

Comment: Check for this matrix, if it is diagonalisable or not.  The statement you mentioned is equivalent with being diagonalisable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that such matrices $A$ satisfy $A^2 = 0$; this implies any eigenvalue $\mu$ of $A$ must vanish, since $Av = \mu v$ for $v \ne 0$  implies $0 = A^2v = \mu^2 v$, forcing $\mu = 0$ since $v \ne 0$.  But then if $D = PAP^{-1}$ were diagonal, we would have $D =0$, since the diagonal entries of $D$ must all be eigenvalues of $A$.  And *this* follows from the observation that any entry $d$ on the diagonal of $D$ satisfies $Dw = dw$ for some $w \ne 0$; taking $v = P^{-1}w$ then yields $PAP^{-1}w = Dw =dw$ or $PAv = dw$ or $Av = dP^{-1}w = dv$, showing $d$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.  Thus $d = 0$.  Thus $D = 0$; thus $A = P^{-1}DA = 0$ as well, contradicting $a_{12} = 1$.  And that's how to prove it.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!! ***